# regular expressions for class name

Tags: c#, html, regex, vb.net

i need a regular expressions string to get all anchor tags in a page with a specific css class name, in c#/vb.net

this is what i got so far

```
"<a.*?href=""(.*?)"".*?>(.*?)</a>"
```

but my attempts to add "class=name" isnt working, also is it possible to find links where the class name appears either before or after the href with one expression ?

i am familiar with 3rd party html libraries, but thats an overkill for what i have in mind, so is the webbrowser control.

Comment: I feel obligated to include [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) answer.  Although your goal is more specific, you will probably get more accurate results with a proper html parser.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that in two steps:

1. find all anchor tags with a regular expression
2. filter out all those that have the incorrect class name.

Answer (score 0):

better not try to parse html with regexes, but use a XML library and use xpath expressions

Comment: Except that html isn't always proper xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="(.*?)" class="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>
```

If you take the second group, that *should* return the class name. I'm presuming that's what you're after.

Edit: Re-read the question... If you're after a specific class name, substitute the second (*.?) with what you want. E.g. if you're after class temp, do:

```
<a href="(.*?)" class="temp">(.*?)</a>
```

Then take the first group for the link, or the second group for the link text.

If you're using it in C#, you will need to escape the quotes. The following should work in C#.

```
string regex = @"<a href=""(.*?)"" class=""temp"">(.*?)</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<1><a *?)(?<2>[^>]*?class=")(?<3>test)(?<4>"[^>]*?>)
```

And do a Replace with

```
$1$2MyClass$4
```

Works for stuff like;

```
<a class="test" href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>
```

**Edit: extracting url**

If you want to extract the URL for a certain class you'll need to use 2 expressions:

```
(?<1><a *?)(?<2>[^>]*?class="test"[^>]*? href=")(?<3>[^"]*?)(?<4>"[^>]*?>)

(?<1><a *?)(?<2>[^>]*?href=")(?<3>[^"]*?)(?<4>"[^>]*?class="test"[^>]*?>)
```

The url is located in group **3**.

First one will match:

```
<a class="test" href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>
```

The second one will match

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="test">Test</a>
```

Comment: Will replace the 'test' class for 'MyClass'

Comment: can you make it wonk on this ? <a randomjunk class="test" randomjunk href="http://www.google.com" onmouseover="" randomjunk  >Test</a> i only need to extract the url

Comment: You need to extract the url for a certain class?

Comment: im doing this now "<a[^>]+href=""(?<1>[^""]+)""[^>]*class=name[^>]*>(?<2>.*?)</a>" it works

Comment: My solution doesn't contain a match for </a> because we really don't need it. We are only interested in the tag itself. With regex we'll always have the problem of "nesting". If we match the </a> we cant parse links in links (which is stupid, but possible).

Comment: Creating and debugging regex can be made easy by using the tool: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RegexWorkbench